# Implementation of a pseudorandom generator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm reading a paper called [More Efficient Oblivious Transfer Extensions with
Security for Malicious Adversaries](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-46800-5_26#page-1) by **Gilad Asharov, Yehuda Lindell, Thomas Schneider** and **Michael Zohner**.

On page 8 they present their protocol. When presenting the tools being used, they write:

[image: pseudorandom generator G]

If my understanding is correct they use a pseudorandom generator called G which **takes as an input an object consisting of zeros and ones of length k and produce an object of zeros and ones of length m**.

My questions is: **How can I implement this in Python?**

How can I implement a pseudorandom generator which takes a seed of size k and produces an output of size m?

Comment: Do you know what `m` is?

Comment: consider how [`random.Random.getrandbits(m)` is implemented where `k=32`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9633cd29b96022bebce4720587b5830551f4af75/Modules/_randommodule.c#L349-L393)

Comment: @mgilson Yes, m is going to be large number, for instance 1000 or 10.000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just always generate [a string of `m` ones :-)](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)  ...

Kidding apart a simple solution is to feed the input number (that will be between `0` and `2**k-1`)  to `random.seed` and then get the result from `random.randrange(1<<m)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use itertools and random.choice()
this one will produce out of '01' with length 40 permutations of size 39,
and islice will get you first 10 out of 1000.

```
>>> li = list(it.islice(map(''.join,permutations('01' * 40, 39)),1000))
>>> item = random.choice(li)
>>> print(item)
010101010101010101010101010101010101010
```