# Implementing a Pseudorandom Generator using AES

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

*"A pseudorandom generator (PRG) is a deterministic algorithm that takes a short uniformly distributed string, known as the seed, and outputs a longer string that cannot be efficiently distinguished from a uniformly distributed string of that length."* [[1](http://scapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/primitives/pseudorandom_generator.html)]

It is my understanding that we can create pseudorandom generators using stream ciphers. For instance, [SCAPI](http://scapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), a Secure Multiparty Computation API, uses RC4 in the [following example](http://scapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/primitives/pseudorandom_generator.html) to create an output of a *fixed* number of bytes (check `out.length`):

```
//Create secret key and out byte array
...

//Create prg using the PrgFactory
PseudorandomGenerator prg = PrgFactory.getInstance().getObject("RC4");
SecretKey secretKey = prg.generateKey(256); //256 is the key size in bits.

//set the key
Prg.setKey(secretKey);

//get PRG bytes. The caller is responsible for allocating the out array.
//The result will be put in the out array.
prg.getPRGBytes(out.length, out);
```

Indeed, pseudorandom generators are particulary useful in some cryptographic protocols (i.e. [this protocol](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/061.pdf)) where we need to create a pseudorandom output of bytes, usually of a very large size, fast.

I have actually implemented [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/061.pdf) protocol using the SCAPI snippet shown above for the PRG part. Yet the authors, instead of using RC4 for their PRG, they use AES128 in CTR mode. Which makes sense since RC4 is known to be broken and since [AES can be easily used as stream cipher](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65085/using-aes-as-a-stream-cipher).

**I want to implement a pseudorandom generator using AES in CTR in the same fashion as the snippet above**, but I'm unable to do so. My problem is not using AES in CTR, there are countless examples online. My problem is the `out.length` part. **I don't know how to implement a PRG using AES** ([or any other cipher for that matter](http://bench.cr.yp.to/primitives-stream.html)) **in a way where I get to choose the exact number of output bytes, like the example above. How can I do this?**

**Before someone mentions that a hash function can do the same job**: Indeed, this is basically a hash function but the problem in this particular protocol is that we need very large outputs (i.e. 32MB) where  a hash function usually has a fixed output of (192, 256, 512 bits).

Finally, this question is not a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108925/implementation-of-a-pseudorandom-generator-in-python) one, because the latter is about implementing any kind of PRG in Python where this is one is about implementing an AES_CTR based PRG in Java.

Some useful links:

- SCAPI's [API](http://cryptobiu.github.io/scapi/)
- SCAPI's [source code](https://github.com/cryptobiu/scapi/tree/master/src/java/edu/biu/scapi/primitives/prg) on PRGs

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm explicitly stating "How can I do this?". This means that I don't expect anyone to do my work. It means "Give me direction" which is what the SE community is all about. I believe that my question is fairly stated and well documented and I don't appreciate your attitude. If you have something to offer to this thread, please do. If you don't, these kind of comments are not constructive at all. From your 5-year experience in this community and your impressive account, you should know that.

Comment: OK, have it your way. I've given a direct answer to your question. Personally I think it is a bit of a generic statement as this more or less explains CTR mode encryption but it does explain how to get out.length bytes.

Comment: I wrote one in [PHP](https://github.com/paragonie/seedspring), but it uses the OpenSSL extension and should be straightforward to reference/rewrite in Java.

Answer (score 2):

In CTR mode you just cut off the bytes you don't need (from the right hand side) of the block encrypt over the last counter. You can create the key stream by performing AES-CTR over the right number (`out.length`) of zero valued bytes as well.

Comment: To check if I got this right: 1. I create a random byte array of the size I want. 2. I cut off any bytes I don't need (if any). 3. I perform AES-CTR over the byte array.

Comment: You can skip #2 of course if you already have the size you want. CTR itself consists of block encrypts of a counter value, so the output would always be N times 16 bytes. In that case you need to cut off some bytes when not required. If you just use AES in CTR mode then the implementation already cuts off the bytes internally, i.e. in the underlying [`CipherSpi`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherSpi.html) instance.